# CesiumJS how to keep the zoom level of a Cesium.Viewer when the viewer.trackedEntity is changed

Tags: cesiumjs

<del>I have 2 different Cesium.Viewer instances, I want sync the 2 viewers when user zoom either one of them.</del>

<del>How to do that?</del>

update:
In my app, I have 2 different Cesium.Viewer instances. But for this question here, I think it has nothing to do with the number of Cesium.Viewer. So I updated the question as below:

I have 2 planes flying on a Cesium.Viewer as shown in the attached screenshot, one is on the red course (ref as red plane) and the other is on the red course (ref as red plane).

Step-1: I tracked the yellow plane by double click it, then it looks like pic-1;

Step-2: I zoom out it to pic-2;

Step-3: I changed to track the red plane by double click it, and it looks like pic-3;

Step-4: I zoom out it to pic-4;

Whenever I changed the tracked entity (as step-3), I need to zoom out it manually again.

**So, my question is how to keep the zoom level when changing the tracked entity?**

[image]

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this question is a little too bare.  Can you post code showing how the two viewers are constructed?  Did you load the same data into both of the viewers?  Do you want the camera pan/tilt to match both viewers, or only the zoom?  Are both viewers viewing in 3D mode?  What's different about the two viewers?

Comment: @emackey thanks for your comments, updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save current camera.view.scene
2. Detect moment when trackedEntity changed
3. Restore camera.view.scene

To save and restore you can use this code as an example:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var savedView = {};

Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load('../../SampleData/simple.czml').then(function(dataSource) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);

    Sandcastle.addToolbarButton('Save View', function() {
        savedView.offset = viewer.scene.camera.position.clone();
    });

    Sandcastle.addToolbarButton('Restore View', function() {
        viewer.trackedEntity._viewFrom._value = savedView.offset;
    });
});
```

Note: viewFrom param should be in source czml for track. Smth like:

```
 "viewFrom": {
    "cartesian": [
      -2080,
      -1715,
      779
    ]
  },
```